# How stretch grid created from data template across entire cell in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm looking for a way to display a nested grid across the entire cell of a parent grid (content). The nested grid (menuContentControl) is created with a data template. The buttons in the nested grid should fill the cells. I create the nested grid and set the row / column with the following code:

```
 ContentControl menuContentControl = new ContentControl();
 menuContentControl.Content = this.menuViewModel;
 menuContentControl.ContentTemplate = this.MenuDataTemplateLeft;
 Grid.SetRow(menuContentControl, 1);
 Grid.SetColumn(menuContentControl, 1);
 this.content.Children.Add(menuContentControl);
```

The data template for menuContentControl:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="MenuDataTemplateLeft">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="button_1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding MenuEntry1Description}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding MenuEntry2Description}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Setting the horizontal and vertical aligment of the data template grid to 'stretch' does not work. Any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: don't understand this ***display a nested grid across the entire cell of a parent grid***, so the nested grid will ***cover*** the parent grid? that does not make much sense without any further explanation. That together with this ***The buttons in the nested grid should fill the cells*** both make no sense. Please explain them more.

Comment: You need to set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" on the content control in order to get the content to stretch. But as the previous comment, I'm not entirely sure what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - Hope this makes it a bit clearer: 'content' is a grid with a couple of columns. A want to display the grid created from the data template (menuContentControl) in row 1 / column 1 of 'content'. menuContentControl should fill the entire cell (row 1 / col 1) it is placed in with the call to Grid.SetRow / Grid.SetColumn.

Comment: Using your code I see the layout is correct, posting a screenshot can help us understand the problem you are facing. By the way, shouldn't the `DataTemplate` be declared with a "x:Key" and referenced by `this.Resources["MenuDataTemplateLeft"]`?